# Bootstrap3 two dropdowns on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make two bootstrap3 dropdown element working on the same line:

I've tried this:

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">first
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
    </ul>


    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">second
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 7</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Unfortunately it seems that the two dropdowns share the same `ul` list (only the second one). How can I bind the first dropdown to its `ul` list and the second one to its own `ul` list too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to separate your `dropdowns` in two `btn-group`:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-inline">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">first
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-inline">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">second
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
    <li><a href="#">Reason 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reason 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reason 7</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/q3yv0ef7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need them in 2 different divs like:

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">first
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">first
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added both `buttons` in   `<div class="dropdown pull-left">`

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
 <div class="dropdown pull-left">   //added this
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">first
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>    //added this
 <div class="dropdown pull-left"> //added this
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">second
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
        <li><a href="#">Reason 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reason 7</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>          //added this
</div>
```

[Demo Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16025/)